# Not understanding Django admin login

Tags: django, redirect, django-admin

I'm trying to use the admin login mechanisms in Django, and redirect to the requested page, and I'm getting a 404 as it's trying to redirect to the url posted, not to the url represented by the next parameter.  I'm obviously not understanding something, because when I step through the contrib.auth.login view, it's not parsing the next parameter at all.  For example, I have the following view (the main page of the site)

```
@login_required(login_url='/sdc/admin/login')
def cb_index(request):
    #snip
    return render_to_response('chargeback_base.html', variables)
```

So when I enter the url for the cb_index view, /sdc/chargeback/, it properly redirects to the login page, with the next variable set to /sdc/chargeback/, as shown below.

```
http://localhost:8000/sdc/admin/login/?next=/sdc/chargeback/
```

The default login view though, from contrib.auth.views, uses that complete url as the redirect_to not the next parameter, so I always get a 404 instead of being redirected to the next url.  I can fix it by adding

```
redirect_to = request.GET.get('next','')
```

to the POST section of the view, but I thought this was supposed to be built in functionality and it's not working.  And more to the point, since this is an edit to the base view, I have to remember to fix this every time I update, which I don't want to do.  What am I not understanding?

EDIT:
Login url follows the admin site urls

```
url(r'^sdc/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

The login template is the included login template from the admin site, no changes.

Comment: edited the question to show that information

Comment: I'm not understanding.  When I step through the code, I'm using the contrib.auth.views.login view, which is the view suggested in the documentation you link to.  Do I have to write a custom login view, calling the auth.login view, and and handle the redirect in my custom view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The django auth app has a login view, which you should explicitly include in your url patterns directly.

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', name='login'),
```

See the [docs on auth views](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L318) for more information. You don't need to choose `/accounts/login/` as your login url. I just want to make it clear that this view is separate from the admin app.

Update [`LOGIN_URL='/accounts/login/'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#login-url) in your settings, then you don't have to use the `login_url` parameter when you use the login_required decorator.

Currently, `/sdc/admin/login/` is handled by the admin app, but the admin app does provide a login view for this purpose. If you step through the code, you can see that the [`AdminSite.login`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L318) method handles the request. This method sets `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME` (in your case 'next')to the request path, then calls the auth login view.

Comment: This worked, but I want to make sure I understand what's going on (my debugger isn't working properly today :-((.  Because I had any sdc/admin urls, including login, handled by the admin app urls, the admin.sites.login method handled the login request.  Admin.sites.login was not handling my redirect to a non-admin page properly, as it was setting the REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME to the full path instead of the path indicated by the next parameter.  By explicitly bypassing the admin app urls and going directly to the auth.login view, this eliminates the issue.  Correct?  Regardless, thanks.

Comment: Yes, you've understood correctly. One other thing to note is that while there is an `AdminSite.login` method, there isn't a specific admin login URL. If you are not logged in and navigate to, for example, `/admin/`, notice that you are not redirected to a login URL. Instead of seeing the view you requested, you see a login form. Once you've logged in, you want to be redirected to your current URL. That's why `REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME` is set to the full path inside the `AdminSite.login` method.

Comment: I see.  I guess that's one disadvantage of the tutorials - it makes it hard to understand how to disentangle the admin, auth, etc, from non-admin apps.  I appreciate the explanations and help!